# How can I stretch my custom ListBox?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have this ListBox with custom elements and I want them to stretch to take all the available area. This is my code; currently the items only take the space that they need and I have some unused space on the left and the right side of the screen. Why?

[image: Here's how it appears]

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Margin="0,6,0,0">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
                        <local:ListTemplateSelector.bloccato>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid Background="Beige">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Assets/Images/locked.png" Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding nomePacchetto}" FontFamily="./Assets/neo-normal.ttf#NEOTERIC" FontSize="48" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FF373737"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Line Stroke="DarkGray" X2="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,6"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ListTemplateSelector.bloccato>
                        <local:ListTemplateSelector.sbloccato>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Foreground="#FF5B5B5B"><Run FontSize="32" Text="1/"/> <Run FontSize="20" Text="40"/></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding nomePacchetto}" FontFamily="./Assets/neo-normal.ttf#NEOTERIC" FontSize="48" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FF373737"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                <Line Stroke="DarkGray" X2="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,6"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ListTemplateSelector.sbloccato>
                    </local:ListTemplateSelector>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: You may read this answer for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927785/stretch-empty-wpf-listview-to-take-the-remaining-space

Comment: @xmashallax this is nothing to do with the dock panels "fill remaining space" functionality, the op has clearly stated that the remaining space is on the left and right of the listbox items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

**(1)**
The easiest way is giving fixed width to your root grid in datatemplate. Though you'll provide fixed width, it will be resolution responsive.

Check this example:

```
       // XAML page
       <ListBox x:Name="lbxTest" Margin="12">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Blue" Width="370" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

If you write your code behind like this:

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>() { "string 1", "string 2", "string 3" };
lbxTest.ItemsSource = lstString;
```

Then in every resolution (480x800, 720x1280, 768x1280, 1080x1920), the size obtained by ListBox will be same.

check the screenshots for refference.

screenshot in 480x800

[image: screenshot in 480x800]

screenshot in 768x1280

[image: screenshot in 768x1280]

**(2)**
The other way to solve this problem is adding one parameter in the ItemSource we'll be assigning to the ListBox.

```
       <ListBox x:Name="lbxTest" Margin="12">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Blue" Width="{Binding width}" >
                        <!--Width="370"-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

// code behind
public class Model
{
    public double width { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}


    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Model m1 = new Model()
        {
            text = "string 1",
            width = lbxTest.ActualWidth
        };
        Model m2 = new Model()
        {
            text = "string 2",
            width = lbxTest.ActualWidth
        };

        List<Model> lstModel = new List<Model>();
        lstModel.Add(m1);
        lstModel.Add(m2);

        lbxTest.ItemsSource = lstModel;
    }
```

Hope this will help..!!

Comment: Using a fixed size fixed my problem in every solution! Easier than I thought! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties that should work but they do not (HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch")

To solve that this example will help you with the witdh:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxInstance"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListBoxInstance, Mode=OneWay}" >
                <Border Background="Red" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <x:String>This is a test</x:String>
            <x:String>This is the second</x:String>
            <x:String>This is the thidr</x:String>
            <x:String>s</x:String>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

As you see with

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ListBoxInstance}"
```

You have the content to the full width.

In some others cases (depending on the platform)

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
  </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: When I apply this property to a list element, it becomes blank... Maybe ActualWidth is set to zero in that moment.

Comment: Yes you need to replace the StackPanel with a Grid over

Comment: This doesn't work, no StackPanel, here's my DataTemplate:

<Grid Background="Beige" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=listBox}">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Image Grid.Column="0" .../>
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" .../>
</Grid>

What's wrong with this? :\

Comment: Have you changed in the ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ?

Comment: <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=listBox}" Background="Red"> here can you add that background, to see how it looks?

Comment: It's totally white, no red background at all, just like the width is set to 0.

Comment: Can you use the first template and remove the itemtemplateselector, I have done and it works, just for testing

Comment: Same thing, I've also used your same code and It's not working! D:

Here's the full XAML page: http://pastebin.com/e5kBTiCK

This is what happens with Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=listBox}" set: http://oi58.tinypic.com/10n58w3.jpg

This is what happens without it: http://oi58.tinypic.com/svmo9x.jpg

Comment: I was testing on Windows 10 but testing now in yours, look what I added in the end

Comment: So you want me to delete the code about the width and insert the code about the ItemContainerStyle? But look at my first post, this is what I was doing before..

Comment: Yes because I did not realize that the failure is <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ListTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
 it should be in <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>

Comment: The member "ItemContainerStyle" is not recognized or is not accessible.
Actually I think I should use ItemContainerStyleSelector, the problem is that this doesn't exist in WP8, the whole ListTemplateSelector does not exist, in fact I did it using this tutorial: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector

This is so frustrating!